# Adding + and - symbols to Voltage Source

Tags: circuitikz

I want to create schematics using circuititkz, and I can't find a way to do this:
I need to use european style symbols, but when drawing voltage sources, I want to display both the arrow AND the + and - symbols next to the source <s>(like there are in the american voltage source symbols)</s> to mark polarity.

This is how I have it set up so far, it looks exactly how I need it to look except for the polarity signs.

```
\usepackage[siunitx, european, straight voltages]{circuitikz}

...

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V=3.0 V] (0,2)
    ...
\end{circuitikz}
```

Unfortunately, the "Sources Customizations" chapter in the circuitikz manual doesn't really provide any answer to this, so I hope someone here can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @JasperHabicht, but that's not what I'm looking for - I need the symbols next to the source, not inside. I was under the impression that american source symbols use the + and - sign outside of the too, that's why I wrote that, but apparently that was wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can always add text nodes outside the components, just name them and use the anchors.  Note that east and west refer to the sides of the component as if it were draw left to right, while the text node offsets are normal.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, european, straight voltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V=3.0 V, n=V1] (0,2);
    \path (V1.ne) node[above] {$+$}
          (V1.nw) node[below] {$-$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]